# Installing a light vim colorscheme on gnome-terminal

Tags: ubuntu, vim, colors, gnome-terminal

I'd like to install a light color scheme for my vim, but it never seems to work (I tried several now). What I'm trying to obtain is something like you can see in this screenshot of mayansmoke: 
[image]

Sadly for me installing this theme looks like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nf1p1dwkisekorm/My_vim.png?dl=0

[image]

Here's my .vimrc:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
set number
set tabstop=3 "tabs are 3 spaces big (smaller than default)
set autoindent "You'll keep the indentation on the next line when you press enter.

"auto complete brackets
inoremap { {}<Esc>i 
inoremap [ []<Esc>i
inoremap ( ()<Esc>i

syntax on
set t_Co=256
colorscheme distinguished
```

Has this to do with the fact that the first screenshot is taken on a mac? 
What could I do to get that kind of light theme?

Comment: Did you try `set background=light`?

Comment: Hi cuonglm, thank you for the answer but that setting doesn't change a thing for me.

Comment: So what `:set background?` return when you set background to light?

Comment: it returns `background=light`

Comment: After reading [distinguished](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-distinguished) homepage, I see that it's a dark colorscheme, Are you sure the example colorscheme is the same with yours?

Comment: Oh my, I should've loaded the mayansmoke colors in stead of the distinguished one.
Man, I'm pretty embarrassed about this! 
The reason I came so fast to the conclussion that my color schemes don't seem to work was that before this trial, I fought a couple of hours with getting the solarized color scheme to work. That didn't work out, and it seems like tons of people have trouble with it, so I left it for what it was.

Anyway, thanks for pointing out this silly mistake!

Comment: @sjbuysse if you want gnome-terminal to be compatible with vim colorscheme, you can use this github (`mkdir -p ~/git; cd ~/git; git clone https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized.git; gnome-terminal-colors-solarized/set_dark.sh` - that will change your gnome-terminal profile to reflect the solarized theme.). Then when you do, `set t_Co=256`,`set background=light`,`colorscheme solarized` in your *vimrc*, it will actually look good (and look good it does)

Comment: Also, if you want the *dir colors* to look good, have a look at https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized (this just configures dircolors so you put `eval \`dircolors /path/to/dircolorsdb\`` in your *bashrc* after you clone or download from the dircolors-solarized github page - `/path/to/dircolorsdb` might be something like `~/git/dircolors-solarized/dircolors.ansi-dark`) this will make `ls --color=auto` look good. :D